# Creating Tag for Changing Dollar Amounts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 3 column SQL table consisting of Company, Price, and Date. I need to indicate in a 4th column generated in SQL what happened to the price (went up from the previous month, went down from the previous month, or stayed the same) by company.

The original table looks like the following

[image: Original Table]

The table I am looking to generate is below, where the 4th column is generated using SQL that takes the price from the previous month into account as well as the company name.

ORIGINAL would be the first price for the first month for a given company, with subsequent months either being UP (if the price went up from the previous month), DOWN (if the price went down from previous month) or SAME as it stayed the same.

[image: New Table]

I have the following SQL to determine if it's the first month for a given company, but not sure how to calculate the amounts in subsequent months as UP, DOWN, or SAME based on the dollar amount for that month compared to previous month for a given company

```
case 
  when row_number() over (partition by u.OrgName order by u.latesttransdate) = 1 then 
 'ORIGINAL MONTH' 
  else 'FUTURE MONTH' 
end
```

Comment: I guess, you need here LAG/LEAD-functionality

Comment: You probably can use `LEAD()`

Comment: Not familiar with that functionality @Sergey - would you be able to share an example using the problem above? Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH TABLE_DATA(COMPANY,PRICE,DATED)
AS
(
   SELECT 'A',1.00,'20210101' UNION ALL
   SELECT 'A',2.00,'20210201' UNION ALL
   SELECT 'A',2.00,'20210301' UNION ALL
   SELECT 'B',1.00,'20210101' UNION ALL
   SELECT 'B',0.50,'20210201' UNION ALL
   SELECT 'B',0.75,'20210301'
)
SELECT X.COMPANY,X.PRICE,X.DATED,
 CASE 
   WHEN X.LAGG IS NULL THEN 'ORIGINAL'
   WHEN X.PRICE-X.LAGG>0 THEN 'UP'
   WHEN X.PRICE-X.LAGG=0THEN 'THE SAME'
   WHEN X.PRICE-X.LAGG<0 THEN 'DOWN'
END AS DIRECTION
FROM
(
  SELECT T.COMPANY,T.PRICE,CAST(T.DATED AS DATE)DATED,
  LAG(T.PRICE)OVER(PARTITION BY T.COMPANY ORDER BY CAST(T.DATED AS DATE))LAGG
  FROM TABLE_DATA AS T
)X
ORDER BY X.COMPANY,X.DATED
```

TABLE_DATA is a data you provided as a screenshot (please never do it again). I am quite lazy that why I have copied only subset of the data to show LAG-functionality
Another small issue is that the string '2/1/21'can be treated differently based on server settings.Please always use ISO-format for dates (YYYYMMDD)

Comment: Thank you Sergey, will make sure not to provide screenshot in the future so that the full data set is available as a SQL statement.